# Twitch bot with node.js

Tags: node.js, twitch

Im new to node and tried to make a simple twitch chat bot with node.js following a youtube tutorial but
everything works untill i try to use "!" command... I use the command and the bot simply doesnt respond to the command.

Here is what i have so far:

```
const tmi = require('tmi.js'),
    {channel , username , password } = require('./settings.json');

const options = {
    options: {debug: true},
    connection: {
        reconnct: true,
        secure: true
    },
    identity : {
        username,
        password
    },
    channel: [channel]
};

const client = new tmi.Client(options);
client.connect().catch(console.error);

client.on('connected', () => {
    client.say(channel, `${username} joined the chat`)
})

client.on('message', (channel, user, message ,self) => {
    if(self) return;
    
    if(message == '!ping') {
        client.say(channel, `@${user.username}, pong`);
    }
});
```

I cant figure it out i just want it to respond

Answer (score 0):

I only played a bit with twitch bots a while ago, but the problem might be the part where you return on self:

```
if(self) return;
```

This means that if a message comes from the bot itself, it will be ignored and the function will return (and therefore stop). Meaning that if you linked the bot to the same account from which you are sending messages, those messages are ignored.

Also:

- you mispelled `reconnect` with `reconnct` in the connection options
- in JS I would recommend to use `===` instead of `==` because the latter attempts to convert and compare operands that are of different types (you can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality))

Edit: what also helps in general is to use `console.log()` to debug and find out where the problem is

Comment: Still doesnt work...

Comment: @Abaddon i really dont see any reason why it shouldnt work... my suggestion is to copy and paste the example code from twitch's documentation https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/get-started/#create-the-botjs-file and see if that works. BTW remember to restart the node program once you modifie the source file to see the changes